# In Power BI my slicers in page are not filtering out the data in page level filters. Is it possible if not can any one help me with work around

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a table called `order` which have columns called `Region` and `OrderNumber`. My client want region as **slicer** in page and `OrderNumber` as a page level filter.  I have a grid visuals which displays details of orders. Grid includes `OrderNumber` column as well. So a sales person click on `region` in slicer and trying to go to select `orderNumber` in page level filter, `OrderNumber` is filtering data based on `slicer`. Is it something that slicers do not interact with page level filter. If yes, help me in providing workaround to make slicer interact with page level filters.

Comment: Adding some example code showing that you have tried will improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the easy way to have another slicer, which contains the `OrderNumber` so that when `Region` selected you'r second slicer would be filtered:

You can also, manage interactive filters upon your requirement as mentioned in screenshots:

[image]